How to Include and Execute External JavaScript in Next.js 15?
I'm new here to Next.js 15 and trying to link an external JavaScript script to a .tsx page in Next.js 15. Similar to how I link scripts in HTML using , I've attempted to include a script in Next.js, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's my setup:
In src/app/page.tsx:
import Image from "next/image";
import Script from "next/script";

<Script src="/components/script.js" />;

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p id="myText"></p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


And in public/components/script.js:
document.getElementById(`myText`).textContent = "Hello, this is a text";

However, the script doesn't seem to be executing when I load the page. Is there a correct way to link and execute an external JavaScript file in Next.js, or is there any alternative method to execute JavaScript scripts in Next.js?
My apologies for this basic question.

You can use that code directly before return like:
import Image from "next/image";
import Script from "next/script";

export default function Home() {
document.getElementById(`myText`).textContent = "Hello, this is a text";
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p id="myText"></p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

Or you can do this:
import Image from "next/image";
import Script from "next/script";


export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
<Script src="/components/script.js" />;
      <div>
        <p id="myText"></p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

